# dgrid - Key tab navigation between editable fields

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm currently trying to create tab-navigation to switch between cell in a d-grid (dojo grid).

I have a grid with all of its cells editable and I want to create a new event to navigate with tab key between cells.

I tried some approachs like:

```
grid.addKeyHandler(keys.TAB, ...
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
grid.on("KeyUp", function (e) {
            if (e.key === "Tab") {
                console.log("Navigate to next cell");
            }
        });
```